# Nginx rewrite static file to versioned file name

Tags: nginx

We want to use the same CSS from our JS app in our server side generated pages. The problem is the CSS file names are versioned by `grunt-rev` like this:

- `main.css` becomes `02668d2c.main.css`

We deploy daily so these static file names change regularly and there is no way for the dynamically server side generated pages to have knowledge of the file names.

**Question:** Is there any way to use NGINX to rewrite requests for `main.css` to `(.*).main.css` ?

Comment: I guess, the point of grunt-rev is to request versioned files. So you do want something strange and meaningless. Just disable grunt-rev if you don't need versioned files.

Comment: @AlexeyTen we need `grunt-rev` and that part is fine. We just need another separate system to be able to load these static assets without knowledge of the versioned part of the file names.

Comment: It will just eliminate all the profit from versioned files. Anyway, nginx can't do that, but you can create symlinks to versioned file while building